# To Reproduce this Header in Latex

Tags: header-footer, rules, resume

[image]

I wish to reproduce this header in Latex, but know not precisely how. So far, I have written:

```
\documentclass{resume} 

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}} 
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}

\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}

\name{\color{coolblack}{Name \vert \textit{Title}}} 
\address{Address • City, Country, Postal Code •  \href{mailto:e-mail}{\textit{e-mail}} • 1230456-789}

\begin{document}
```

though know not how to form that double-line underneath.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Should these header lines be displayed on every page of the document, or just on a specific page? Which document class do you employ? (Some document classes provide more built-in capabilities than others do.) How wide is the textblock of your document? Do you need to employ a specific font face? Please advise.

Comment: Those header lines are only to appear on the _first_ page of the document, whose class will be a _resume_. I think I shall be using the standard font of Latex (_Knuth's Computer Modern_), and there are to be margins around each page of these dimensions: [left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in].

Comment: Off-topic: `left=0.4 in,top=0.4in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.4in` may be expressed more succinctly as `margin=0.4in` (or, possibly, `margin=1cm`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (I had to use the `article` document class because I don't seem to have access to the `resume` document class.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}  % I don't seem to have access to the 'resume' class

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry} % document margins
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{coolblack}{rgb}{0.0, 0.18, 0.39}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % to use "|" symbol in text mode
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=black]{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth} @{}}
\large\color{coolblack} 
Name \quad|\quad \itshape 
Title \\
\small
Address \quad\textbullet\quad 
City, Country, Postal Code \quad\textbullet\quad 
\href{mailto:xyz@someplace.net}{\textit{email}} \quad\textbullet\quad 
123-456-789 \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```